# Executing a Script by matching two file with regex in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to Chef. I have a file version.txt in my chef node.I write a recipe to execute a script in the chef node.  I upload the another version.txt file with different version(i.e content). I want to execute the script only the current version.txt files contains higher value than the previous one? How to do with this regex? How to compare two files with regex?

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare the files, instead you tell Chef what you want the content of the file to be and Chef will enforce that. If the file was already there but with the old version it will be updated, or if it didn't exist it will be created. You can use notifications to trigger running the script only when the contents of the file change.

Comment: how to do the notifications to trigger running the script? Can you give one example with syntax?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Chef syntax, I recommend starting with something like http://learnchef.com/ as a tutorial. Notifications are added to the resource like `notifies :run, 'execute[/path/to/my/script]'` where `execute '/path/to/my/script'` it another resource you have defined elsewhere and `:run` is the action you want to execute.